# Accessing Office ribbon objects (buttons/groups) when they are loaded with GetResourceText

Tags: xml, ms-office, vsto, ribbon

I have a VSTO for Word with 2 ribbons. One is built in the designer and I can access their properties from the code with

```
Me.myButton1.label = "My Button Label";
```

But the other is dynamic and is loaded with

```
GetResourceText("filename.xml");
```

where the XML has a format like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
      <ribbon>
        <tabs>
          <tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="My Tab">
            <group id="grpProperties" label="Properties">
              <button id="btnProps" imageMso="PropertySheet" onAction="btnMainForm" label="Change properties" size="large" />
            </group>
          </tab>
        </tabs>
      </ribbon>
    </customUI>
```

Which works fine and both ribbons show up in Word. This xml file has groups and buttons with IDs. 
But I can't access their properties as their object IDs are unknown. How can I access a group or button label in my code?

Comment: You can't. What is it you want to do with them? For some things there are attributes that link to "callbacks" in your code, such as the `onAction` attribute in your snippet. Anything you want to do has to be done using callbacks. If you haven't done so already, I recommend the 3-part "Customizing the Office 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon" series https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)

Comment: What I wanted to do is to put the version number on the label of the first group. On the fixed ribbon I added `Dim _V As Version = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion
    Me.grpProperties.Label = "Ribbon v" & _V.ToString()` and I wanted to do that on the dynamic ribbon too. This saves time for support when users have problems that may already be fixed. Updating vsto's sometimes takes a while ... and i didn't want to put a button on the ribbons to display the installed version. Using callbacks is not going to help here I'm afraid. ideas?

Comment: Behind the scenes, VSTO uses the same callback technology. So what you do with the Ribbon Designer should also work for RibbonXML. The button control has a `getLabel` callback. The callback will be run automatically when the Ribbon is loaded by VSTO. Have you read the documentation I recommended?

Comment: yes, I read that document a couple of times. It's quite exactly how I built my ribbons :) unfortunately, using properties or methods like getLabel() need an objectID first which I can't seem to find for the dynamic ribbon. The document doesn't mention how to access those. Surely there is a way to enumerate the objects from the ribbon after it's initialized with a custom XML?

Comment: When you ADD a Ribbon XML part to your solution it creates an XML and a code page, such as Ribbon1.XML and Ribbon1.vb (or cs). There's a list of instructions at the top of the code page and some sample code. Use the [edit] link under your question to copy/paste that code page into your Question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after. I revised your XML and included the callbacks for `getLabel` in C#, VB.NET & VBA.

In my Addins, I put the about information as a group in the ribbon to the far right. Here's my **[GitHub Project](https://github.com/Excel-projects/Script-Help/blob/master/README.md)** where I load the about information from the project settings. Also, I use **[Log4Net](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial)** to log all errors from my deployed VSTO Addins. You can have the log file written to a shared folder on your network; I usually just have it under the install folder of the click once deployment path. In the log file, you can capture the version, machine name, user name, etc.

[image: screenshot]

#### Here's an example with your XML (formatted using [Notepad++ XML Tools plugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XML%20Tools/))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab 
                    idMso="TabAddIns" 
                    label="My Tab"
                    >
                <group 
                        id="grpProperties" 
                        getLabel="GetLabelText"
                        >
                    <button 
                            id="btnProps" 
                            imageMso="PropertySheet" 
                            onAction="btnMainForm" 
                            label="Change properties"
                            size="large" 
                            />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

#### C# Callback for the label text

```
public string GetLabelText(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    try
    {
        switch (control.Id)
        {
            case "grpProperties":
                return "My Addin 1.0";
            default:
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

#### VB.NET Callback for the label text

```
Public Function GetLabelText(control As Office.IRibbonControl) As String
    Try
        Select Case control.Id
            Case Is = "grpProperties"
                Return "My Addin 1.0"
            Case Else
                Return String.Empty
        End Select

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "error"

    End Try

End Function
```

#### VBA Callback for the label text

```
Public Sub GetLabelText(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef label)
On Error GoTo ErrTrap

    Select Case control.id
        Case Is = "grpProperties"
            label = "My Addin 1.0"
        Case Else
            label = ""
    End Select

ExitProcedure:
    Exit Sub

ErrTrap:
    label = "error"
    Resume ExitProcedure

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate response! But responding to callbacks is what I do. To get the `control.id` at that point is a reactive way which would work and what I think @Cindy tried to tell me too. It would require a user to click a button before I can get to the control ID's. It's not exactly what I'm looking for. I want to get the ID's of the controls at the initialization time in the `OnLoad` function.

Comment: @kjoetools I read your comments, that you wanted to put the version number for support in a label. You can do this with the callbacks

Comment: @kjoetools, Maybe it would help me understand your question a bit more, if you explained why you want the ids.

Comment: I'm updating our ribbons on a regular basis but not all users get the updates right away. I want to put the version number of their installation in the label of the first group of both ribbons. That works fine when i design the ribbon because I have the Me.groupObjectId.label but with the dynamic ribbon where i load the xml with a GetResourceText() the ID's i define in the xml are not available in the 'onload' function and I can't reach the ID of any object on the ribbon. I dont want to wait for a user to click a button but present him with the current version at load time.

Comment: You can set the label of any control with the callback `GetLabelText`